# Develop .net pages on sharepoint online except using visual web parts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

How can I develop web pages with .net on sharepoint online. A way is using visual web parts. Is there any other way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Web Parts, if you use the Sandbox Solutions.  You'll need to put code in those which that type of solution is being deprecated.  Instead you should be build a SharePoint App.   There are three (3) types of hosting, SharePoint hosted, Auto hosted and Provider hosted.

SharePoint hosted will generally allow you to host .js and .html/.aspx files.

Auto hosted and Provider hosted will allow you to write server side code.  The different being that Provider hosted will require that you provide a web server, and Auto hosted will put a simple web site and SQL Azure database in Azure for you.

All three of these can create App Web Parts which is generally the same thing as a Visual Web Part, except that they will be using an iframe to include you web app.